# How to use \labelformat for lstlisting (with listings package) so that \vref (of varioref package) gives "Listing 1.1 on page x"?

Tags: listings, varioref

I want to reference listings (with listings package) via \vref (from varioref)
analogous to figures. So I'm looking for the analogue to
\labelformat{figure}{Figure~#1}. What is the name of the appropriate counter, ie
what must be in place of the question marks in \labelformat{???}{Listing~#1}?

I've tried below and a few others. But I only get "Pls see 1.1" instead of "Pls see Listing 1.1".

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[nospace]{varioref}
\labelformat{lstlisting}{Listing #1}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=A, label=lst:a]
  some code
\end{lstlisting}

Pls see \vref*{lst:a}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\labelformat{lstlisting}{Listing~#1}`

Comment: I've tried that in the above example. I still get 1.1 instead of "Listing 1.1". If I move `\labelformat{lstlisting}{Listing~#1}` to below `\begin{document}`, it seems to work. Is it supposed to be there? For `\labelformat{figure}`, I have to put it in the preamble.

Comment: move it behind begin document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an unknown reason listing defines its counter only in the begindocument hook. So you must do the change later:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[nospace]{varioref}
\AddToHook{begindocument}{\labelformat{lstlisting}{Listing #1}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=A, label=lst:a]
  some code
\end{lstlisting}

Pls see \vref*{lst:a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It's good we have a solution answered here. I could only find one other page where a workaround for this problem is mentioned. I only get to that page via google search only by chance. It's not written in English either. I had to use google translate.

Comment: @PyiSoe maybe open an issue with the maintainer, I think it is not good if such counter declarations are delayed unless there is a very good reason.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach, I've reported the issue to the maintainer.